# dual of quotient abelian variety

Tags: abelian-varieties

Let $A$ be an complex abelian variety and $S\subset A$ a finite subgroup.

> How to calculate the dual abelian variety of $A/S$?

Comment: There is an exact sequence $0\rightarrow \hat{S}\rightarrow \widehat{A/S}\rightarrow \hat{A}\rightarrow 0$. See Mumford's *Abelian varieties*, §15, Theorem 1.